# Mysql Fetch Records When Foreign Key Value Is Zero

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, null

I've created some tables as follows.

```
countries

con_id   con_name
99       India
100      China

cities

cty_id     cty_name         country_id
1          Bangalore        99
2          Chennai          99
3          Delhi NCR        99

fees

f_id     st_dt        end_dt        city_id         country_id
1        2014-05-05   2014-05-05    1               99
2        2014-05-10   2014-05-10    2               99
3        2014-05-15   2014-05-15    3               99
4        2014-05-20   2014-05-20    0               100
5        2014-05-22   2014-05-22    0               100
```

I'm writing a query fetch the records from `fees` table by `country_id` as follows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fees as fe
JOIN countries as con
   ON con.con_id = fe.country_id
JOIN cities as cty
   ON cty.cty_id = fe.city_id
```

For country `india`, it fetches first `3` records from fees table and for country `china`, its not fetching any records due to `joinings`.

So I want the results like `null for city columns` and `correct values for fees and country tables`.

Please help me how to get the solution for this. The work would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` (or right, depending on the join sequence):

```
SELECT *
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN fees f
  ON c.con_id = f.country_id
LEFT JOIN cities ci
  ON ci.country_id = c.con_id
```

The left join will fill with nulls the columns which don't have a match in the join.